# Preview of JPG Test plan attachments doesn't working

Tags: azure-devops, tfs, test-plan

hey  we are trying to enable preview on the jpg  test plan attachments but it doesn't working .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgTQ6.png)can someone advice about it please ?

to see as preview the jpg attachment in my test plan case results .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.